# How to import data from absolute path in a csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV containing n records and it is filled with absolute paths to the images. I'd like to import those images into a numpy matrix.

[image: data in csv]

Comment: Did the solution helped or needs an edit?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def load_image( infilename ) :
  img = Image.open( infilename )
  img.load()
  data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
  return data

df = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')

for i in range(len(df)) : 
  print(load_image(df.iloc[i, 0]))
```

You can store the returned values in list if you want else directly use.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps. :D

Comment: Is there a way to load the images that are in the same row at once? I just have two columns.

Comment: can you provide sample output ? df.iloc[i,1] can load image from second column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `read_csv` function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')
print (df)
```

Source: https://datatofish.com/import-csv-file-python-using-pandas/

Comment: but that will just print the raw path that's present in the csv. Instead I want to read the image in the path.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468558/adding-image-to-pandas-dataframe