# How to use styler with an HTML pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a df with pictures in it by following [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468558/adding-image-to-pandas-dataframe). I want to style the df with some conditional formatting using [pandas styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). However, for the images show up you need to turn the pandas df into an HTML df, and in order to style a df, you need to turn the df into a styler object. Is there any way to style a dataframe with images?

To get images

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML

df = pd.DataFrame([['A231', 'Book', 5, 3, 150], 
                   ['M441', 'Magic Staff', 10, 7, 200]],
                   columns = ['Code', 'Name', 'Price', 'Net', 'Sales'])

# your images
images = ['https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/7/7a/Mage%27s_book_detail.png/revision/latest?cb=20180310083825',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d9/5c/9b/d95c9ba809aa9dd4cb519a225af40f2b.png'] 


df['image'] = images

# convert your links to html tags 
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html)))
```

to style

```
import seaborn as sns

cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
s
```

I would *really* like to be able to style a dataframe with pictures, but I can't seem to figure out the object types. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, you just need to call the [format method of the Styler object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)
`s.format({"image": path_to_image_html})`

If you want the html from this resultant Styler object, just use the render method: `s.format({"image": path_to_image_html}).render()`