# IPython.core.display.HTML to png

Tags: python, html, pandas, png

Following this thread
[Adding image to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468558/adding-image-to-pandas-dataframe/53469293)
I use `path_to_image_html` to display some png (actually charts from matplotlib) inside my df pandas dataframe.

```
def toto():
   df['imageUrls'] = images1
   def path_to_image_html(path):
       return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'
   return HTML(df.to_html(escape=False,formatters=dict(imageUrls=path_to_image_html)))
```

And then `display(toto())` to display my pandas inside my jupyter notebook.

Now I would like to save my pandas in a PNG file format.
Basically convert toto() to a png file.

How can I proceed ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use: [`imgkit`](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/)

```py
import pandas as pd
import imgkit

test = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4], 
                     "percentage": [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]})

imgkit.from_string(test.to_html(), 'out.png')
```

Comment: Yes and my toto() function should  return directly df.to_html(escape=False,formatters=dict(imageUrls=path_to_image_html))
Thk !

Comment: Notes:
1) `Install wkhtmltoimage`
2) Then `pip install imgkit`